# JSON.Net error reading

Tags: json.net

I'm trying to parse some JSON data with Json.Net. Here is my data:

```
[
    {
        "UIDClan": "1",
        "UIDKnjiga": "1",
        "Naslov": "Title1",
        "DatumZaKada": "2013-08-09 00:00:00",
        "DatumIstekRez": null,
        "Spremno": "0"
    },
    {
        "UIDClan": "1",
        "UIDKnjiga": "2",
        "Naslov": "Title2",
        "DatumZaKada": "2013-08-08 00:00:00",
        "DatumIstekRez": null,
        "Spremno": "0"
    },
    {
        "UIDClan": "1",
        "UIDKnjiga": "3",
        "Naslov": "Title3",
        "DatumZaKada": "2013-08-09 00:00:00",
        "DatumIstekRez": "2013-10-09 00:00:00",
        "Spremno": "1"
    }
]
```

With this piece of code i want to extract UIDClan data:

```
 JObject o = JObject.Parse(s);

 Console.WriteLine(o["UIDClan"]);
```

The error is

> Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.

I've checked with JSONLint and it's valid.

The examples that I found doesn't start with [.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You could try using a `JArray`.
This JSON data is actually an array.

```
JArray v = JArray.Parse(s);
```

To get the first item.

```
var firstItem = v[0]["UIDClan"].ToString();
```

You can even use linq

```
var items = v.Where(x =>  x["UIDClan"].ToString() == "1").ToList();
```

Comment: what if my object was just a single string? JObject.parse fails for the same reason and unfortunately for me, there is no JString.parse...

Comment: just answered my own question. JRaw.Parse seems to work with a string

Comment: how can I get all indexes in my web service json response ? I mean I don't wanna get item that index 0.I wanna get whole json list response to my list how can do that ?My Code is [here](https://pastebin.com/7VcL0Piu)

Answer (score -1):

To overcome the error plz serialize the jsonstring in below format.this serialize string we are able parse as Jobject

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {JsonString})
```